# How to handle session id from expressjs behind a apache2.4 webserver

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, proxypass, session

I have a apache 2.4.29 with TLS activated to handle static files. Then i have a proxy configured to pass dynamic content to a NodeJS 10.5.0 with:

- ExpressJS 4.16.3
- express-session 1.15.6
- session-file-store 1.2.0

The site.conf in apache that configures the proxy to Node is:

```
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
            RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.0/8
            RequestHeader add X-SSL off
            ProxyPass "/s"  "http://127.0.0.1:3001"
            ProxyPassReverse "/s"  "http://127.0.0.1:3001"
            RewriteRule ^/s/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:3001/$1 [P,L]
            ProxyPass "/n"  "http://127.0.0.1:3001/n"
            ProxyPassReverse "/n"  "http://127.0.0.1:3001/n"
            RewriteRule ^/n/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:3001/n/$1 [P,L]
```

The Node/Express is without the TLS configuration. Both are on the same machine.
In the server.js i have this code to handle the sessions:

```
var express = require('express'),
    sessao = require('express-session'),
    armazenamento_ficheiros = require('session-file-store')(sessao),
    app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(sessao({
    store: new armazenamento_ficheiros(),
    secret: 'teste',
    name: 'xxx',
    resave: true,
    cookie: {secure: false }, //i also tried with true, auto and removing the property
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

The problem is that it is appearing a session id JSON file for each client request for a dynamic file, instead of using just one. Also, it appears a cookie id session in the browser with a id that did not appeared in the session id files of Express. I removed and repeated to see it the cookie was created again and now it does not. I am already confused with so many testing.

Can anyone guide me how to solve this correctly? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I changed the script to:

`app.use(sessao({
    store: new armazenamento_ficheiros(),
    secret: 'teste',
    name: 'xxx',
    resave: true,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {secure: true },
    saveUninitialized: true
}));`

And now, if i use the URL to access directly to the NodeJS, it works as expected; it creates a cookie with session ID. But it i access via Apache, i can see the set-cookie command in the http header received but the browser does not create the cookie. I suspect that somethins is wrong in the Apache configuration.

So i added: RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the small problems with the ExpressJS and Apache configurations, the finnal problem where the missing credentials option in the fetch request from the JS.
More details here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133939/apache2-49-cookies-not-working-via-my-proxypass-virtualhost/51137357#51137357)